# What is the best way to read in a text file from the server in asp.net-mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, text-files

In one of my controller actions I need to read in a text file that has a bunch of reference data in it. Right now I simply put it in the "/Content" directory.

My questions are:

1. Is this the "right" place to put this file or should I put it in another directory?
2. What is the best way to read in a text file in asp.net-mvc that is sitting on the server?

Comment: "right" depends on a lot of things; size, nature, how often it is updated, etc

Comment: use this library easy to implemet in asp.net http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: really. use a library to read a text file?!

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Read-a-Text-File-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If the file should not be directly available via URL, you should put it in App_Data.

For reading it, just use:

```
var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt"));
```

Comment: if the file should be available for public put it in the Content or Upload (if uploaded) folders

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt") works too if Server is not easy to come by.

Comment: Doesn't work for me because this results includes the routing of the url.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when I publish the project to server, but in debug mode using HostingEnvironment.MapPath works

Comment: Is there any architectural concerns for just creating a ViewBag.Property in the cshtml file itself or should this file content be served from the Controller? I have several files with static text for certain pages (poor man CMS) and I don't think it'd be a good fit for a database because the data will rarely EVER change.

Answer (score 23):

Ok this way it works for me (VS2017)

1. Set the Build Action of the file.txt to *Content*
2. Check if Copy to output directory is **not** set to 'Do not copy'
3. Use `HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt")` (thanks to Hong comment)

   ```
   var fileContents = 
       System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/file.txt"));
   ```

Comment: This seems to be the answer for 2017+